# Question on data binding, live data and drawable

Tags: android, android-databinding, android-livedata

I am trying to data bind a drawable with live data and am running into this error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to call observer method
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
```

My xml fragment (only pasted the relevant portion)

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>
        <import type="androidx.core.content.ContextCompat" />
        <variable name="location" type="String"/>
        <variable name="viewModel"
            type="com.marty.dang.polarpointsweatherapp.presentation.viewmodel.DailyWeatherViewModel"/>
    </data>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/homeFrag_weather_icon"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"

            android:src="@{ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, viewModel.iconObservable)}"

            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/homeFrag_title_text_view" />
```

My view model (only pasted the relevant portion)

```
val iconObservable: MutableLiveData<Int> by lazy { MutableLiveData<Int>() }

    private fun determineWeatherIcon(weatherDescription: String)  {
        val icon = when(weatherDescription){
            "Thunderstorm" -> R.drawable.thunderstorm_icon
            "Drizzle" -> R.drawable.rain_icon
            "Rain" -> R.drawable.rain_icon
            "Snow" -> R.drawable.snow_icon
            "Clear" -> R.drawable.sun_icon
            "Clouds" -> R.drawable.cloudy_icon
            else -> R.drawable.cloudy_icon
        }

        iconObservable.postValue(icon)
    }
```

My drawable folder

[image: Drawable Folder]

However, If I just use a regular variable and not a mutable live data variable, it works fine.

```
var weatherIcon = R.drawable.snow_icon

private fun determineWeatherIcon(weatherDescription: String)  {
    weatherIcon = when(weatherDescription){
        "Thunderstorm" -> R.drawable.thunderstorm_icon
        "Drizzle" -> R.drawable.rain_icon
        "Rain" -> R.drawable.rain_icon
        "Snow" -> R.drawable.snow_icon
        "Clear" -> R.drawable.sun_icon
        "Clouds" -> R.drawable.cloudy_icon
        else -> R.drawable.cloudy_icon
    }
}

android:src="@{ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, viewModel.weatherIcon)}"
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: did you set the `viewModel` to binding class from fragment/activity ?

Comment: @ManoharReddy 
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(layoutInflater, R.layout.fragment_daily_weather, container, false)
        binding.lifecycleOwner = this
        return binding.root
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `app:imageResource` property in your xml:

```xml
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>
        <variable name="location" type="String"/>
        <variable name="viewModel" type="com.marty.dang.polarpointsweatherapp.presentation.viewmodel.DailyWeatherViewModel"/>
    </data>
    
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/homeFrag_weather_icon"
        app:imageResource="@{viewModel.iconObservable}"
        ... />
...
```

In your viewModel you should have the following property:

```kotlin
val iconObservable: MutableLiveData<Int>
```

And you can have the following method:

```kotlin
private fun determineWeatherIcon(weatherDescription: String)  {
    iconObservable.value = when(weatherDescription){
        "Thunderstorm" -> R.drawable.thunderstorm_icon
        "Drizzle" -> R.drawable.rain_icon
        "Rain" -> R.drawable.rain_icon
        "Snow" -> R.drawable.snow_icon
        "Clear" -> R.drawable.sun_icon
        "Clouds" -> R.drawable.cloudy_icon
        else -> R.drawable.cloudy_icon
    }
}
```

You don't need `postValue`, unless you're setting the value in a background thread.

In your fragment class, you should set the `viewModel` and the `lifecycleOwner` to your `binding`:

```kotlin
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    binding = YourFragmentBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
    binding.viewModel = viewModel
    binding.lifecycleOwner = viewLifecycleOwner
    return binding.root
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Using app:imageResource fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

iconObservable.value
try this on your xml and it will work

Comment: Setting it like this still gives me an error. android:src="@{ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, viewModel.iconObservable.intValue())}"